# Requests to localhost from within a view cause the server to stop responding

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, python-requests, djoser

I am using [Djoser](https://djoser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) to create an authentication backend. I want the following to happen:

1. User registers at `http://localhost:8000/auth/users/` with email, username, password, and re_password
2. User receives an activation email at the email they entered with a URL to activate their account. The URL is of the form: `<web url>/activate/{uid}/token` (eg: `http://localhost:8000/activate/Mg/apur8c-6100390a061c5ff081235193867f943a`)
3. Clicking on that URL sends a GET request to the server where a view (`UserActivationView`) receives the extracted uid and token and sends a request of its own to `<web url>/users/activation/{uid}/token` (`http://localhost:8000/users/activation/Mg/apur8c-6100390a061c5ff081235193867f943a`). And returns the response that it gets from that request as *its* response.
4. User account gets activated.

This is the code that does all of the above:

```py
# Djoser configuration in settings.py
DJOSER = {
    'LOGIN_FIELD': 'email',

    'PASSWORD_RESET_CONFIRM_URL': 'password-reset/{uid}/{token}',
    'USERNAME_RESET_CONFIRM_URL': 'username-reset/{uid}/{token}',

    'SEND_ACTIVATION_EMAIL': True,
    'ACTIVATION_URL': 'activate/{uid}/{token}',

    'SEND_CONFIRMATION_EMAIL': True,
    'PASSWORD_CHANGE_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION': True,
    'USERNAME_CHANGED_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION': True,

    'USER_CREATE_PASSWORD_RETYPE': True,
    'SET_PASSWORD_RETYPE': True,
}
```

```py
# views.py in user app (users/views.py)
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
import requests


class UserActivationView(APIView):
    def get(self, request, uid, token):
        protocol = "https://" if request.is_secure() else "http://"
        web_url = protocol + request.get_host()
        post_url = web_url + '/auth/users/activation/'
        post_data = {'uid': uid, "token": token}
        print(f"Sending request to {post_url} with {post_data}")
        result = requests.post(post_url, data=post_data)     # <<-- causes the server to hang
        return Response(result.text)
```

```py
# users/urls.py
from django.urls import path, include
from .views import UserActivationView

app_name = "users"

urlpatterns = [
    path('auth/', include('djoser.urls')),
    path('auth/', include('djoser.urls.jwt')),
    path('activate/<str:uid>/<str:token>/',
         UserActivationView.as_view())
]
```

```py
# MAIN project urls.py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('chat/', include('frontend.urls')),
    path("chat/", include('backend.urls')),
    path('api/accounts/', include('backend.urls')),
    path('', include('users.urls'))

]
```

Now, the problem arises in step 3 (at the `result = requests.post(post_url, data=post_data)` line). When the view attempts to send a post request the server hangs for quite some time. During this, it doesn't even halt when I do <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>. This is the output that I get (I have added comments):

```py
HTTP POST /auth/users/ 201 [5.87, 127.0.0.1:56239] ## User registration was successful and email was sent
HTTP GET /activate/Mg/apuvq9-3461158f807a1e054738458bc2372486 301 [0.00, 127.0.0.1:56245] # 301 response while trying to GET the URL sent in the email
Sending request to http://localhost:8000/auth/users/activation/ with {'uid': 'Mg', 'token': 'apuvq9-3461158f807a1e054738458bc2372486'} # My print statement
# A long pause here. Server hangs and then this error appears:
Application instance <Task pending coro=<StaticFilesWrapper.__call__() running at D:\pigeon\venv\lib\site-packages\channels\staticfiles.py:44> wait_for=<Future pending cb=[_chain_future.<locals>._call_check_cancel() at C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\asyncio\futures.py:348, <TaskWakeupMethWrapper object at 0x000001E3EDE96858>()]>> for connection <WebRequest at 0x1e3edd8a788 method=GET uri=/activate/Mg/apuvq9-3461158f807a1e054738458bc2372486/ clientproto=HTTP/1.1> took too long to shut down and was killed.
Application instance <Task pending coro=<StaticFilesWrapper.__call__() running at D:\pigeon\venv\lib\site-packages\channels\staticfiles.py:44> wait_for=<Future pending cb=[_chain_future.<locals>._call_check_cancel() at C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\asyncio\futures.py:348, <TaskWakeupMethWrapper object at 0x000001E3EE1067C8>()]>> for connection <WebRequest at 0x1e3edd8a788 method=GET uri=/activate/Mg/apuvq9-3461158f807a1e054738458bc2372486/ clientproto=HTTP/1.1> took too long to shut down and was killed.
Internal Server Error: /activate/Mg/apuvq9-3461158f807a1e054738458bc2372486/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\pigeon\venv\lib\site-packages\asgiref\sync.py", line 482, in thread_handler
    raise exc_info[1]
  File "D:\pigeon\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 38, in inner
    response = await get_response(request)
  File "D:\pigeon\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 238, in _get_response_async
    )(e, request)
  File "D:\pigeon\venv\lib\site-packages\asgiref\sync.py", line 444, in __call__
    ret = await asyncio.wait_for(future, timeout=None)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\asyncio\tasks.py", line 414, in wait_for
    return await fut
concurrent.futures._base.CancelledError
```

Alternatively, if I manually send an activation request via Postman or a separate Python script then the request works just fine and the user is activated:

[image]
[image]

The problem only seems to arise when the request is made from within the view to the server. I also tried `result = requests.get('http://localhost:8000/chat')` as an experiment and it too caused the server to hang whereas `result = requests.get('http://google.com')` causes no such issues.

The view's code was taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47159919/11573842) and someone under the answer also [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47154404/djoser-user-activation-email-post-example#comment118873861_47159919):

> This hangs my debug django server – Hack_Hut Apr 25 at 11:55

How can I resolve this?

I am using:

- Python: 3.7.5
- Django: 3.2.5
- Djoser: 2.1.0
- Django rest framework: 3.12.4
- Requests: 2.26.0

Comment: What Python | Django | Django Rest Framework are you using?

Comment: @angardi I have updated my question, please have a look

Comment: The user activate URL `auth/users/activation` should be sent from your frontend app, not from your backend. Also take note that activation URL `activate/{uid}/{token}` should be the frontend page URL that your email should direct users to because this page would be sending the POST request to `auth/users/activation` and handling the result from there.

Comment: @Scratch'N'Purr yeah, that makes sense. The frontend could extract the uid and token and post it at the activation endpoint and redirect the user to the home page if a proper response is returned else show the error.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I'm facing the same issues. I think this is happening only when we execute requests.post() against localhost.

Answer (score 0):

Late answer but adding in case it's helpful to any future readers. I'm running into this issue myself. I have two views, one that POSTs back to localhost:8000/api/ and another that makes a GET request back to localhost:8000/api/ and both requests were working when running locally with Django `./manage.py runserver` but starting hanging and killing the worker when testing with gunicorn.

While I agree with @Scratch'N'Purr that those requests should really be coming from the front, I did find a solution.

I believe what is happening is gunicorn is running by default on a single worker/thread. This is causing gunicorn to deadlock as the second request (the GET or POST back to localhost) is waiting for the worker for free up.

When I finally thought to increase the workers/threads (in my case using docker-compose)

```
    command: financial_wiz.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 --workers 4 --threads 2
```

It freed right up and starting acting as expected.